# Android Studio build failed after upgrading to capacitor 3 in an IONIC project

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic4, capacitor

I did an upgrade to Capacitor 3 in an Ionic Project.
What I did so far : I followed the upgraade instructions on the capacitor page.
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0

The Ionic-Build succeeds, however, when I try to build the solution for my Android device in
the Android Studio (latest version) I got the following error:
(Sorry, I'm not allowed to add pictures right now)

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find org.apache.cordova:framework:7.0.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/cordova/framework/7.0.0/framework-7.0.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/cordova/framework/7.0.0/framework-7.0.0.pom
> -file [MY_PATH]/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs/framework-7.0.0.jar
> -file:[MY_PATH]/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs/framework.jar
> -file:[MY_PATH]/ScannerApp/android/app/libs/framework-7.0.0.jar
> -file[MY_PATH]/ScannerApp/android/app/libs/framework.jar

Required by:
project :app > project :capacitor-android
project :app > project :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution : in the build.gradle I had to change following section :
(Comment out mawenCentral() and use jcenter() )

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        //mavenCentral()
    }
}
```